# Determining if a set is convex, and if not, finding a convex relaxation

Tags: convex-analysis, hessian-matrix, relaxations

This is for an advanced course in Chemical Engineering, and I do not have much previous experience with matrix mathematics so this question has me stumped.

The way the material was presented, it seems like we should use the Hessian to determine if the set is convex (basically, if the Hessian is greater than zero for all variables?). These are the first two of five problems:

1. $\{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$,
2. $\{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$.

I think I'm doing the Hessian correctly 
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

But what throws me off is the difference between the two: how do I incorporate the inequality versus the equality that sets the two apart when trying to determine if each set is convex?

Comment: If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ belongs to the given set, check whether $\alpha(x_1,y_1)+(1-\alpha)(x_2,y_2)$ aldi belong to the set for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$

Comment: one of these sets is not convex... Take $(1,0),(-1,0)$, these vectors belong to both sets, however $(0,0)=(1,0)/2+(-1,0)/2$ does not.

Comment: convexity of sets and convexity of functions are different. Checking Hessian is for the later one, when the function is continuously differentiable. (Moreover, when checking Hessian, we require positive semidefiniteness, and need to check the sign of each principal minor of the matrix.)

Comment: To say that a set $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ is convex means that if $x$ and $y$ are points in $S$ then every point on the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ also belongs to $S$. If you draw a picture of these two sets, you can immediately see which is convex and which isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you are supposed to use is:

> A set $X$ is convex iff for all continuous functions $f$ from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ (with the discrete topology), $f$ is a constant function.

But I am not quite sure how to use this approach. Instead consider using the definition of a convex set.

> A set $X$ is convex iff $\forall a,b\in X: tb+(1-t)a\in X, \text{where } t\in[0,1]$.

With this definition and noting that the set $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le1\}=\{\vec{x}\in\Bbb R^2:||\vec{x}||\le1\}=:B_1\left(0\right)$, consider $a,b\in B_1\left(0\right)$. Then: 
$$||tb+(1-t)a||\le||tb||+||(1-t)a||=t||b||+(1-t)||a||\le t(1)+(1-t)(1)=1$$
Now it follows that $tb+(1-t)a\in B_1\left(0\right)$ and since $a,b$ were arbitrary, the set is convex.

Comment: That statement at the top of your answer looks more like a criterion for connectedness than convexity...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it made me realize I misread the question, and messed up. Should I delete this answer?
EDIT: Wait, I was reading up and found [this](https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_1.pdf)... I think I'm actually correct...